# Lombok with Jackson Deserializer from camelCase

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

Here is a simple Object

```
@Builder
@Value
@JsonDeserialize(builder = User.UserBuilder.class)
class User {
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    private final string userName;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class UserBuilder {}
}
```

Now, if I want to use `ObjectMapper` to read a string to this, I do

```
final User user = MAPPER.readValue("{\"user_name\":\"my-name\"}", User.class);
```

But this does not read the `user_name` because when I look at the generated source code for the builder, I see

```
public static final class UserBuilder {
    private String userName;
}
```

And so the camelCase doesn't match the snake_case. Normally if I were to manually generate the Builder class, I would put `@JsonProperty("user_name")` on the builder property as well.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Lombok supports copying annotations to the builder methods using the config parameter `lombok.copyableAnnotations`. However, this copies the annotation to the method's parameter (and not to the method), which does not help here. Unfortunately, there is no easy solution for this, because some annotations only work on the parameter. See https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1961 for a discussion on this topic.

Comment: @JanRieke wait. But I do want the annotation to go on the parameter, and not the method; i.e. I want the parameter `private String userName;` inside the `UserBuilder` to also get the `@JsonProperty("user_name")` annotation.

Comment: Copying the annotation to the internal field of the builder is also not supported (and IMO not a good solution anyway, even if it works with Jackson).

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the ObjectMapper to convert camel case to names with an underscore :

```
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
```

Comment: I don't want my object mapper to worry about this. I want the deserializer to take care of this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own constructor for the `Builder` to use with underscore parameter names:

```java
@Value
@JsonDeserialize(builder = User.UserBuilder.class)
class User {
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    private final String userName;

    @Builder
    public User(String user_name) {
      this.userName = user_name;
    }

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class UserBuilder {}

}
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose of using Lombok! I don't want to create a builder or a constructor!

Comment: And 10 different elements to make it work with jackson doesn't defeat its purpose? Besides, you have public constructors with no validation now?